# How can I tell if visiting a URL would download a file of a certain mimetype?

Tags: http, header, mime-types

I am building an application that tells me if visiting a URL would make a user download a file of a certain mimetype.
My question is: What information (like header fields) can be used to achive this?

I was thinking about sending a HEAD-request and look for Content-Disposition and Content-Type header fields. But an attacker might just lie in this fields and because of mimesniffing my browser would still save the file.

Is there a way to get this information without downloading the file (this would cause unwanted traffic.)

EDIT:
I want to develop an application that gets an URL as input.
The output should be three things:
1: does visiting the URL make browsers save ("download) a file delivered by the webserver?
if 1:
2: what is the mimetype of this file?
3: what is the filename of this file?

Example:
The url https://foo.bar/game.exe visited with a browser saves the file game.exe
How could I tell (without causing huge traffic by downloading the file) that the url will: 1: make me download a file 2: application/octet-stream 3: game.exe

I already know how to make a head request. But can I really trust the Content-Disposition and Content-Type header fields? I have observed responses that did not contain a Content-Disposition field and my browser still saved the file. This would cause my application to think the URL is clear while it isn't.

Comment: This is looking more like a programming question than a security one. And what do you mean by "downloading"? What do you mean by "makes/lets you download"? Do you mean automatic file downloads?

Comment: Have you looked at things like https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-downloads-chrome-firefox-windows

Comment: The browser knows the filename, because that's the name of the file. I'm getting the impression that there is more context here or you have not explained everything yet.

Comment: What if a separate request (e.g. from JavaScript or a redirection) actually initiates the download?

Comment: Edited my question. I think this should not have been moved to stackoverflow since I am not asking a programming question. I want to discuss if http header fields alone can be trusted to make sure a user won't save/download a file of a certain mimetype when visiting a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers do not guess the mime type if the type is present in the content-type header (see [MDN:Mime Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_Mozilla_determines_MIME_Types))

So, you can rely on if that and/ or the content-Disposition header is present that the browser will not guess.

Now, in order to  detect what it is you are getting, the best way is to request the head of the file (the first line / few bytes) and decipher the magic value from that. (e.a. the *NIX way to determine what a file is)
this is more reliable and less risky than depending on the file extension...

but if you need a fool proof methode to determine if a file will be downloaded.. there is n't one I know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `curl`, with the `-I` option (to fetch headers only), like so:

```
curl -I https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf
```

Comment: this is why i originally posted the question on security instead of stackoverflow. I already know how to do a header request. My problem is that for malicious websites those headerfields might lie and browser are so "intelligent" they still save a file, while my application was unable to notice that a file is delivered.